# How to get over path requried error in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to make this web page to upload the books and there links but it always show the following error

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
    const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        authour: {
            type: String,
            required: true
            
        },
        discription: {
            type: String,
        },
        link: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
        
    })
    
    const Book = mongoose.model('books', BookSchema);
    
    module.exports = Book ;
```

This is the schema I am using but it keeps showing

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: 

    ValidationError: books validation failed: link: Path `link` is required., authour: Path `authour` is 

    required., name: Path `name` is required.                                   at 

    model.Document.invalidate (E:\mystletainn\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2688:32) a
```

app.js code that I have been using

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//const methodOverride = require('method-override')


const books = require('./models/books');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/books', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true 
      })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("MONGO CONNECTION OPEN!!!")
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("OH NO MONGO CONNECTION ERROR!!!!")
        console.log(err)
    })

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'))

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//app.use(methodOverride('_method'))

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.query;
    if (name) {
       const book = await books.find({name})
        res.render('main', { book, name })
    } else {
        const book = await books.find({})
       res.render('main', { book })
    }
})
app.get('/upload', async (req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.query;
    if (name) {
       const book = await books.find({name})
        res.render('/', { book, name })
    } else {
        const book = await books.find({})
       res.render('upload',{book})
    }
})
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {

    const newBook = new books(req.body);
   // await newBook.save();
    console.log(newBook)
    res.redirect(`/`)
})
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("LISTENING ON PORT 3000")
})
```

I have tried to resolve it but it is always giving the same error I am not able to save this to the `const newbook.even` the console.log shows only the id not the form data

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `link.required` to `false` or send it with your request body.

Comment: i am sending it with the request body but req.body is not visible in newbooks all I get is a id

Comment: Log `req.body`.

Comment: i have value in console.log but when I log new books it only show id

Comment: What value in console.c?

Comment: i get all the form entery in log(req.body) like this  [Object: null prototype] {                                                                                                                                                                                                    'name ': 'The Purpose-Driven Life: What on Earth Am I Here For?', and so on

Comment: Try `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));`.Install `body-parser` first.

Comment: Do you use `multipart/form-data`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your post method in something like that,

```
 const newBook = new books({
name:req.body.name,
authour:req.body.author,
discription:req.body.description,
link:req.body.link
})
```

Comment: thanks for the help but it seems the problem was not in the app.js file it was in the HTML file it was a mismatch in input.name property I added some extra space in there.